# How do you access an endpoint using a tag?

Tags: java, spring

I am currently working on passing spring VMware exam. One of questions in spring boot actuator section ask about accessing endpoint using a tag. After searching for answer in documentation(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.monitoring) and Internet. I did not find a clear answer. Any help?

Comment: if you by "endpoint" you mean API, most APIs don't support this, so they should be passed as query perhaps with ? or a post payload. but # won't work i guess!

Comment: Well exact question from guide is "How do you access an endpoint using a tag?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the question is referring to the `/metrics` endpoint specifically. You can find the documentation about tags here:

- [18.2. Retrieving a Metric](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#metrics.retrieving-metric)
- [18.3. Drilling Down](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#metrics.drilling-down)

Look at the "`availableTags`" for a given metric (using the `/actuator/metrics/{metric.name}` endpoint). Then you can add any number of `tag=KEY:VALUE` query parameters to the endpoint URL to filter down the data.

The example shown in the documentation is that the metric `jvm.memory.max` has a tag `area` with possible values `heap` and `nonheap`. So I could request:

`/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max?tag=area:nonheap`

...to see just the max nonheap memory.

Comment: Note: I learned all this information by typing "How do you access an endpoint using a tag?" (in quotes) into a search engine, which identified a lot of blog articles with the answer, then from there I looked up the official documentation around `availableTags`. That process should help you with other questions on your exam prep journey if StackOverflow cannot. Good luck!